Karate Cucumber Test report shows blank Video file for UI Test Execution
I am trying to execute Karate UI test on dockerTarget Chrome container , in the Cucumber test report the video is blank.
I connected to the docker container and could observe the file present .I was able to manually copy the file to localhost.
Not sure why its not happening automatically after the test ends.
Below is the code for dockerTarget init:
Scenario: Chrome Docker Instance Initializer

configure driverTarget = { docker: 'karatelabs/karate-chrome' ,start:false, showDriverLog: true      ,beforeStart: 'supervisorctl start ffmpeg', afterStop: 'supervisorctl stop ffmpeg',videoFile: '/tmp/karate.mp4'}

configure retry = { count: 7, interval: 5000 }



Karate Execution Log is below where video file missing is mentioned.
13:21:43.417 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.http.WebSocketClientHandler - websocket client disconnected
13:21:43.418 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - custom target configured, attempting stop()
13:21:43.419 [1722239503418] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - command: [docker, stop, e231184e93ffd78336a7475ee965dd4f427659d7d4a08fcb8be8f3a828e627fa], working dir: null
13:21:44.255 [1722239503418-out] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - e231184e93ffd78336a7475ee965dd4f427659d7d4a08fcb8be8f3a828e627fa
13:21:44.276 [1722239503418] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - command complete, exit code: 0 - [docker, stop, e231184e93ffd78336a7475ee965dd4f427659d7d4a08fcb8be8f3a828e627
fa]
13:21:44.277 [1722239504276] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - command: [docker, cp, e231184e93ffd78336a7475ee965dd4f427659d7d4a08fcb8be8f3a828e627fa:/tmp, target\karate-chrome_e231184e93
ff], working dir: null
13:21:44.447 [1722239504276-out] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - symlink 5185464003818643869 C:\GitHub-ABCTEST\myPROJECT\target\karate-chrome_e231184e93ff.com.google
.Chrome.H2kL8Q\SingletonCookie: A required privilege is not held by the client.
13:21:44.474 [1722239504276] WARN com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - exit code was non-zero: 1 - [docker, cp, e231184e93ffd78336a7475ee965dd4f427659d7d4a08fcb8be8f3a828e627fa:/tmp,
target\karate-chrome_e231184e93ff] working dir: null
13:21:44.475 [1722239504475] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - command: [docker, rm, e231184e93ffd78336a7475ee965dd4f427659d7d4a08fcb8be8f3a828e627fa], working dir: null
13:21:44.690 [1722239504475-out] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - e231184e93ffd78336a7475ee965dd4f427659d7d4a08fcb8be8f3a828e627fa
13:21:44.704 [1722239504475] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - command complete, exit code: 0 - [docker, rm, e231184e93ffd78336a7475ee965dd4f427659d7d4a08fcb8be8f3a828e627fa
]
13:21:44.704 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN com.intuit.karate - video file missing: target\karate-chrome_e231184e93ff\karate.mp4
13:2
Expecting the Karate execution video file to be available in the Cucumber Report after the Test ends.

It appears in the Karate report. I think to appear in the Cucumber report needs some work, do consider contributing code or getting your team to do so
